# Sending normal-urgency notifications via notify-send

Tags: command-line, python, 15.04, notify-osd, irssi

I'm currently on 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) and I can't seem to get any notifications to show unless they're sent with the urgency set to critical, like so:

`notify-send -u critical "IRC" "This is a critical IRC notification`

unlike this, which doesn't work:

`notify-send -u normal "IRC" "This is a normal IRC notification"`

I'm using this as a test to troubleshoot [irssi-libnotify](https://code.google.com/p/irssi-libnotify/), which is sending the notifications to the server correctly, but they aren't being shown because they're normal-urgency. I would rather not modify the python script as a work around, since this might be an issue for future packages.

Comment: Have you forgot to add a double quote at the and of your command?

Comment: Hrm, having same issue that it only works with critical. I also seem to be getting delayed messages from a while ago. I have a feeling there might be a queue stacked up.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1501328/652

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is

```
notify-send [OPTIONS] <summary> [body]
```

Eg:

```
notify-send -u normal "Hello World" "Have a nice day"
```

Have a look at [man notify-send](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/notify-send.1.html)

If you want to use an other library (in your case  irssi-libnotify) and there is a bug, create an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/stickster/irssi-libnotify).

---

*Example*

```
notify-send -u critical "IRC" "This is a critical IRC notification"
```

[image]

Comment: @Eunkai: As you're a reputation 6 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: I don't think this a bug with the library, but might have something to do with the OS. On both irssi-libnotify and notify-send, the notification doesn't show unless it's sent with `-u critical`. The command suggested by A.B. doesn't work, but the same command with `normal` replaced with `critical`, displays fine.

Comment: The issue is that I want normal-urgency notifications, because critical notifications stick on-screen for thirty seconds and aren't dismiss-able, which is rather annoying.