# notify-send only works with sudo

Tags: permissions, notify-osd, dbus, notify-send

**Problem**

```
sudo notify-send Test "Hello World"
```

Displays a notification as expected.

```
notify-send Test "Hello World"
```

Does not display a notification.

**Further information**

Ubuntu version 16.04.

The notifications appear to use notify-osd instead of notification-daemon. Running notify-send appears to launch a notify-osd process under the user that ran notify-send. I'm not sure what dbus is.

**No error messages**

There are no errors in the syslog. When I run the following code no error messages occur.

```
#include <libnotify/notify.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    gboolean x = notify_init ("Hello world!");
    printf( "notify_init: %d\n", x );
    NotifyNotification * Hello = notify_notification_new ("Hello world", "This is an example notification.", "dialog-information");
    GError *err = NULL;
    x = notify_notification_show (Hello, &err);
    printf( "notify_notification_show: %d\n", x );
    if(err != NULL) {
        printf("Error detected!\n");
        printf("Error message:%s\n", err->message);
    }
    else {
        printf("No error detected.\n");
    }
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(Hello));
    notify_uninit();
    return 0;
}
```

I do not know what I'm doing. Thanks for the help.

**Python Notify**

In the past, I've used a python program that has working notifications. I tested a hello world notification and it works without sudo!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import gi
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import Notify

Notify.init("test")
n = Notify.Notification.new('test', 'test2')
n.set_urgency(Notify.Urgency.CRITICAL)    
n.show()
```

Code from http://www.devdungeon.com/content/desktop-notifications-python-libnotify

I am not sure why this works. The python Notify is just wrapping the library used in the C example. I'd prefer not to use python but will if I must.

**Edit**

The problem occurred again. Resolved by adding urgency critical.

Comment: Is there another user account on your system to check if it is also on other users? Another question: did notifications work fine in the past on this account, also from cli?

Comment: No there isn't another desktop user. I can add one and check. This is my first time using notifications but volume control  and a bunch of other ubuntu built-ins display notifications. Add python test to post.

Comment: Did the issue by any chance *start* when you ran the command `sudo notify-send...`?

Comment: No. I'm pretty sure I ran notify-send first. Then decided to try sudo because then the computer knows I really mean it.

Comment: Restarting the computer has fixed the problem. Notify-send now no longer requires sudo. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am not sure I was of any help :), but great that it is fixed :)

Comment: Andrew, maybe we should close it as not reproducable?

Comment: You can do that!

Comment: I need at least 300 reputation to add the "close" tag. I'll just accept the answer below. I tried breaking it again by running sudo and another custom notification program but no luck.

Comment: Don't worry, it will get closed over time if a few more people see it. Don't delete, it is a waste of your + 5, and the question is well- documented.

Comment: I'm leaving it just in case some one else runs into it. Wasted a couple hours trying to figure this out :(

Comment: Occasionally , notifications can get blocked (for whatever reason), so in that case you can try  setting urgency level. `notify-send --urgency="critical" "Hello" "World"`.

Comment: I have the same problem on same setup and reboot doesn't fix it. A bash script I use regularly use it and someday stop working. I check `/usr/bin/notify-send` permissions and are OK (755). Also tried purge/install. Command end silently with exit status code 0. Urgency level don't change anything. libnotify-bin v0.7.6-2svn1, notify-osd v0.8+15.10.20151016.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting fixed the problem. Not sure why.

**Edit**
The problem occurred again. Using urgency critical caused the notification to appear. The command is:

```
 notify-send --urgency="critical" "asdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

With [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/346580/349837) I "fixed" the problem. No `sudo` needed now. Have to set again `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable:

```
eval "export $(egrep -z DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS /proc/$(pgrep -u $LOGNAME gnome-session)/environ)";
```

But, as [asked here](https://askubuntu.com/q/650385/349837):

- `notify-send -u critical "Nice title" "Nice description"` work fine but
- `notify-send -u normal "Nice title" "Nice description"` doesn't work.

Also using `-i` this way seems deprecated: `notify-send -i "notification-network-wireless-full" "Summary" "Body"`. Maybe we should [file a bug](https://launchpad.net/notify-osd).