# Low urgency alerts from notify-send never appear

Tags: notify-send

The `man` page for `notify-send` says that the urgency level can be low, normal, or critical:

```
   -u, --urgency=LEVEL
       Specifies the urgency level (low, normal, critical).
```

However, while normal and critical alerts appear (critical ones need to be manually dismissed; normal ones disappear by themselves after a short wait), low ones never appear. This is irritating, as I commonly use `alert` to let me know when a long-running process has finished.

```
$ type alert
alert is aliased to `notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e 's/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//')"'
```

I suppose I could re-write `alert`, but it seems more sensible to try to work out what's suppressing low-urgency notifications. They used to work. It stopped somewhat recently.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

In a related issue, someone else had it even worse: they [could only see critical notifications](https://askubuntu.com/q/650385/652). I can see normal and critical, but not low. (That question has an answer which does not actually address the issue.)

Comment: This appears to be by design: "Low priority notifications are added to the Message Tray without being displayed as a banner." https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/Notifications/TopRight

Comment: Ah, that's a change, then. Because they certainly used to appear. I suppose re-writing `alert` is the only option which makes sense, in that case.

Comment: That said, my notifications appear top centre, not top right. But they appear the same as those in the screenshots there, so it's presumably the same code under the hood.